# Remove chapter and title from book

Tags: chapters, titles, books

I need my chapter to appear in the list of contents, but it can't show in the page it starts. The titlesec package helped, but it just erased the "chapter n" part, and I need to delete the chapter name too.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Title}` might be what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Secret chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to have a "ghost chapter title", so that the text starts in the same position. This is the reason for the `\null` command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp\space \thechapter}{\null}{}{}
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{#1}{\null}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A phantom title}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The same result can be achieved without `etoolbox`, with:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{50\p@}%
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \if@mainmatter
  \huge\bfseries \null %<--- modified
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 20\p@
  \fi
  \fi
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \Huge \bfseries \null\par\nobreak % <--- modified
  \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother
```